# How to use Nokogiri::HTML.fragment without creating unwanted custom tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have Ruby code that supports HTML fragmentation with Nokogiri.

When user input text with `"<"` to the application, `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment` make it to the custom HTML tag.

If a user enters text like

```
"One <two three"
```

the application will display it like

```
"one <two three></two>"
```

I'm using `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html, encoding = 'UTF-8')`.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you give a clear example of what you are trying to achieve. An example input and expected output.

Comment: currently my input is "One <two three" and out put it "one <two three></two>", expected out put is "One <two three". this code line take my input and brake it to html fragments, Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(input, encoding = 'UTF-8').
I want stop creating custom html tags like <two>.

Comment: Don't add clarification into a comment, instead add it to your question as if you'd included it initially, without "Edited" or some such marker. Comments are for asking for clarification and providing information to the person asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're not understanding how HTML is different than text to a parser. Nokogiri thinks that `one <two three` is HTML and tries to validate it, sees `<two three` and thinks it's a tag `<two` followed by a parameter, but doesn't see the closing `>` so it does some fix-up trying to be helpful.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('one <two three') 
doc.to_html # => "one <two three></two>"
```

Instead, just as if you wanted to create a page containing `one <two three`, you have to provide HTML encoded text:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('one &lt;two three') 
doc.to_html # => "one &lt;two three"
```

You could automate this using the HTML Entities gem:

```
require 'htmlentities'
coder = HTMLEntities.new

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(coder.encode('one <two three'))
doc.to_html # => "one &lt;two three"
```